# Binding datagrid to sum

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, xaml, datagrid

In mypage.xaml I have retrieved an `ObservableCollection(Of MyObject)`.
To fill (almost all) columns of my datagrid `MyDataGrid` automatically I placed a binding programatically like  this

```
Class myPage
Private _context As New MyData

Private Sub Page_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    _context.MySubObject.Load
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = _context.MySubObject.Local
End Sub
End Class
```

and I bound 2 columns of `MyDataGrid` to 2 properties of `MySubObject` like this

`<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>`

`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>`

This works fine. 
Now, I want to bind a 3rd column. My issue is, the 3rd property of `MySubOject` is an ObservableCollection of `AnotherObject`. I want to display the number of objects of `AnotherObject` for each `MySubObject` that is displayed, like:

```
ID | Name | NumberofAnotherObjects
----------------------------------
1  | abc  | 42
2  | def  | 56    
3  | xyz  | 592
```

My idea would be to remove the existing bindings and create a LINQ query for all three. But I don't know how to dynamically build this sum in LINQ. Could you please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: so, is it sum or count? if count: simply bind column to collection Count property `"{Binding AnotherObjectsCollection.Count}"`

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collections have `Count` property which can be used in binding

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="NumberofAnotherObjects" 
                    Binding="{Binding AnotherObjectsCollection.Count}"/>
```

ObservableCollection additionally provides notification when Count changes (items added/removed)